# PDE solution in a different spatial domain

Tags: matlab, pde

I have a time-dependent PDE solution `T(k,i)` k runs over time steps (i.e., `k=1:nt`) and i runs over spatial steps (i.e., `i=1:Nx`)

My question is: How can I assign a new solution `NewT(k,j)=T(k,i)` that runs over a different spatial domain `j=1:Ny` in order to change the shape of the new function?

regards

Lama

Comment: Your question is rather unclear to me. What is the correlation between `j` and `i`?

Comment: Basically both of them run over spatial coordinate steps. T(k,i) is the solution of the PDE equaton for xmin, xmax and dy. I need now to change its profile (to make it wider that extends both xmin and xmax) therefore, I have proposed a way where I can define a new spatial domain that has ymin<xmin, ymax>xmax and dy=dx. However, I can't assign the solution T(k,i) to a new function inside the new domain.

Comment: What I'm doing now is analysing the thermal distribution of two thermal sources. By solving the PED for both of them and then add the resulting solutions to each other, you get the thermal profile of both thermal sources. But the thing is that adding both solution doesn't reflect the reality as both sources affect each other, so the resulting profile has to be a bit wider and higher.